# Jquery Regex to fetch number after $ symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi I am trying to write a small script which gets all the amounts in a page(Amazon).

This is what I have come up with to store the values in an array.

```
var amounts= $('*').text().match(/^\$[-0-9.,]*/);
```

But this code is not working because in the actual page there is some text/tags before the $ symbol like

> `<p>$500</p>`

Can someone pls correct my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had luck with this on amazon

```
var arrayPrices = document.body.textContent.match(/\$\d+\.?\d+/g);
```

[image]

Comment: Todd, tried your code, but looks like something is wrong, I tried it on this page http://www.amazon.com/oc/echo/. I am getting 4 values ["$100", "$199", "$99", "$100"]. $100 is repeated twice, if you check the page, it is available only once.

Comment: My bad, the source code had two values, which was hidden. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
str.match(/^\$[-0-9.,]*/) could be

var arr=str.match/\$\d+(\.\d+)?/g
```

To match all the integers and (possible) decimal strings that follow a dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reggae grouping like this

```
 var str = "$500";
 var array = "/\$(\d+)/".exec(str);

 alert(array[1]);
```

in array[0] you will find the String str. In array[1] the first hit and so on.